# send push notifications between phones

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am searching for a way to send push notifications between windows phone devices without using a windows form. Basically I have been attempting to allow toast and tile notifications sent by a single client application to one or more of the same client application on other phones. 
Ultimately I would like to use push notifications as 'status' updates where one user would notify any other user of his or her choice that a task is ready to be completed, in progress, or completed (possibly involving changing the color of the updated tiles to say green, yellow, or red along with sending a toast notification and udpating a tile's text depending on the task's status)
Is this even possible? What I have seen so far involves sending such notifications through windows form applications, but I would like to make my service completely mobile. Any linkes, code suggestions, or advice would be greatly appreciated I've only built the most basic of push notification applications thus far!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the other terminal's push URI you can easily POST a message to this URI, so I think your challenge is reduced to exchanging these between the clients and then follow the approach detailed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202967(v=vs.92).aspx. The only difference is that you would rather use a WebClient to POST the message than a web form.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik Hartz. What would you recommend as the best method to exchange the push URI between clients? I am kind of confused of how to create the WebClient within the notification example to create an efficient client application that handles both tasks of creating a URI as well as allowing users to communicate via tile notifications between this URI? I would like to update tiles like in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202970(v=vs.92).aspx and also use toast notifications if the application is not loaded.

Comment: I assume you would need to do this via a web service - i.e. report the URI to the web service, and offer an API to send push notifications to other registered subscribers instead of sharing the actual push URI. The application/service/game you mention in your initial question sounds like a sensible location to add this.